# NestedScrollView doesnt show cards with wrap content and dynamic data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dynamic

I have an activity with view pager and I'm loading fragments which has `NestedScrollView` as parent with cards in it. The data in the card is loaded dynamically and doesn't have fixed height. The card's `height` is set to `wrap_content`.

The problem is that the `NestedScrollView` is not displaying the cards properly after the data is loaded. In some cases the cards overlap each other, while in some,  the cards are not visible at all (usually the last).

The activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_generic_candidate_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.interviewair.interviewairforemployer.ui.genericCandidateProfile.GenericCandidateProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout_all"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar_genericcandidateprofile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@color/black" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_black_24px"
                        android:tint="@color/white"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        android:alpha="0.7"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleimageview_genericcandidateprofile_photo"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_outline_white_48px"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="1.5dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_genericcandidateprofile_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_medium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_genericcandidateprofile_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:alpha="0.8"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_work_black_18dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_genericcandidateprofile_location"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:alpha="0.8"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_18px"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Mumbai, Maharashtra"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_genericcandidateprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout_genericcandidateprofile_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/grey500" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_genericcandidateprofile_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_white_24px"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragment that is being loaded:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_overview_skills"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_overview_skilltitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/text_skills"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

            <com.dpizarro.autolabel.library.AutoLabelUI
                android:id="@+id/autolabel_overview_skillchips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview_overview_skilltitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                autolabel:label_background_res="@drawable/custom_rounded_background"
                autolabel:label_clickable="false"
                autolabel:show_cross="false"
                autolabel:text_color="@android:color/black"
                autolabel:text_size="@dimen/di_text_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_overview_retry_skills"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24px"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_overview_skillpb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_overview_preferredlocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_overview_skills"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_overview_loctitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_preferred_location"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

            <com.dpizarro.autolabel.library.AutoLabelUI
                android:id="@+id/autolabel_overview_preflocchips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview_overview_loctitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                autolabel:label_background_res="@drawable/custom_rounded_background"
                autolabel:label_clickable="false"
                autolabel:show_cross="false"
                autolabel:text_color="@android:color/black"
                autolabel:text_size="@dimen/di_text_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_overview_retry_loc"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24px"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_overview_locpb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_overview_personal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_overview_eduexp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_overview_personaltitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/text_personal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_overview_personalwrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/text_email"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_overview_email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/text_mobile"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_overview_mobile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/text_dob"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_overview_dob"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/text_gender"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview_overview_gender"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/di_text_regular" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_overview_retry_personal"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey_background"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24px"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_overview_personalpb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```